# Adding new category from alertdialog to spinner

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

```
btn_cat.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(final View view){
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext(),R.style.AlertDialogTheme);
                final EditText edittext = new EditText(getContext());
                alert.setTitle("New Category");

                alert.setView(edittext);

                alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        //What ever you want to do with the value

                        String newCat = edittext.getText().toString();
                    }
                });

                alert.show();
            }
        });
        String[] values =
                {"- Select Category -", "Entertainment", "Drink & Food", "Gift", "Health", "HouseHold", "Shopping", "Transport", "Others",};
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_exp);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_exp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, values);
        adapter_exp.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter_exp);
        adapter_exp.notifyDataSetChanged();
        adapter_exp.add(newCat);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `String[] with ArrayList<String>`

then

```
 alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        //What ever you want to do with the value

                        String newCat = edittext.getText().toString();

valuesArrayList.add(newCat);
adapter_exp.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
```

EDIT FULL CODE:

```
  btn_cat.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(final View view){
                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext(),R.style.AlertDialogTheme);
                    final EditText edittext = new EditText(getContext());
                    alert.setTitle("New Category");

                    alert.setView(edittext);

                    alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            //What ever you want to do with the value

                            String newCat = edittext.getText().toString();

        valuesArrayList.add(newCat);
        adapter_exp.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });

                    alert.show();
                }
            });

    ArrayList<String> valuesArrayList = new ArrayList<>;
    valuesArrayList.add("- Select Category -");
    valuesArrayList.add("Entertainment");
    valuesArrayList.add( "Drink & Food");
    valuesArrayList.add(  "Gift" );
    valuesArrayList.add( "HouseHold" );




            Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_exp);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_exp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, valuesArrayList);
            adapter_exp.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter_exp);
            adapter_exp.notifyDataSetChanged();
           // adapter_exp.add(newCat);
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return view;

        }
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply but can you make it full , sorry about that but i am new in this

Comment: pls check and add more items in array list

Comment: Not working  valuesArrayList.add(newCat);
        adapter_exp.notifyDataSetChanged(); Redline with Can't resolve symbol

Comment: Thank You So much

Answer (score 0):

```
final ArrayList<String> valuesArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    valuesArrayList.add("- Select Category -");
    valuesArrayList.add("Entertainment");
    valuesArrayList.add( "Drink & Food");
    valuesArrayList.add(  "Gift" );
    valuesArrayList.add( "HouseHold" );




    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_exp);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_exp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, valuesArrayList);
    adapter_exp.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter_exp);
    adapter_exp.notifyDataSetChanged();

    btn_cat.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(final View view){
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext(),R.style.AlertDialogTheme);
            final EditText edittext = new EditText(getContext());
            alert.setTitle("New Category");

            alert.setView(edittext);

            alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    //What ever you want to do with the value

                    String newCat = edittext.getText().toString();

                    valuesArrayList.add(newCat);
                    adapter_exp.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

            alert.show();
        }
    });[enter image description here][1]
```